# How to remove redundant data using mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables the cbfm_carp_data and cbfm_carp_data2
I want to join them in one table with matching values not IDs

I have tried this MYSQL query

Table 1 - cbfm_carp_data

```
  Municipality | PO_representative 
  Patnongon    | ABISFUFAI
```

Table 2 - cbfm_carp_data2

```
  Municipality | year_planted | sepcies_planted
  Patnongon    | CY 2007      |40 has
  Patnongon    | CY 2011      |30 has
  Patnongon    | CY 2011-2013 |60 has
  Patnongon    | CY 2016-2018 |90 has
```

My query

```
 SELECT 
 n.Municipality,n.PO_representative,s.year_planted,s.species_planted
 FROM cbfm_carp_data n
 JOIN cbfm_carp_data2 s ON n.Municipality = s.Municipality
```

This is the result of my query

```
  Municipality | PO_representative | year_planted | sepcies_planted
  Patnongon    | ABISFUFAI         |CY 2007       |40 has
  Patnongon    | ABISFUFAI         |CY 2011       |30 has
  Patnongon    | ABISFUFAI         |CY 2011-2013  |60 has
  Patnongon    | ABISFUFAI         |CY 2016-2018  |90 has
```

This is the result I want to get

```
  Municipality | PO_representative | year_planted | sepcies_planted
  Patnongon    | ABISFUFAI         |CY 2007       |40 has
               |                   |CY 2011       |30 has
               |                   |CY 2011-2013  |60 has
               |                   |CY 2016-2018  |90 has
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36348733/3110834

Comment: actually your codes doesnt work when dynamically add an event but if we use the properties it works well. Thank you

Comment: How about the second column ?